# 'Maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000' error with Grails and Oracle

Tags: oracle, grails, grails-orm

I'm using Grails with an Oracle database. Most of the data in my application is part of a hierarchy that goes something like this (each item containing the following one):

- Direction
- Group
- Building site
- Contract
- Inspection
- Non-conformity

Data visible to a user is filtered according to his accesses which can be at the Direction, Group or Building Site level depending on user role.

We easily accomplished this by creating a listWithSecurity method for the BuildingSite domain class which we use instead of list across most of the system. We created another listWithSecurity method for Contract. It basically does a Contract.findAllByContractIn(BuildingSite.listWithSecurity). And so on with the other classes. This has the advantage of keeping all the actual access logic in BuildingSite.listWithsecurity.

The problem came when we started getting real data in the system. We quickly hit the "ora-01795 maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000" error. Fair enough, passing a list of over 1000 literals is not the most efficient thing to do so I tried other ways even though it meant I would have to deport the security logic to each controller.

The obvious way seemed to use a criteria such as this (I only put the Direction level access here for simplicity):

```
def c = NonConformity.createCriteria()
def listToReturn = c.list(max:params.max, offset: params.offset?.toInteger() ?: 0)
{
    inspection {
        contract {
            buildingSite {
                group {
                    'in'("direction",listOfOneOrTwoDirections)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting Grails to generate a single query with joins that would avoid the ora-01795 error but it seems to be calling a separate query for each level and passing the result back to Oracle as literal in an 'in' to query the other level. In other words, it does exactly what I was doing so I get the same error.

Actually, it might be optimising a bit. It seems to be solving the problem but only for one level. In the previous example, I wouldn't get an error for 1001 inspections but I would get it for 1001 contracts or building sites.

I also tried to do basically the same thing with findAll and a single HQL where statement to which I passed a single direction to get the nonConformities in one query. Same thing. It solves the first levels but I get the same error for other levels.

I did manage to patch it by splitting my 'in' criteria into many 'in' inside an 'or' so no single list of literals is more than 1000 long but that's profoundly ugly code. A single findAllBy[…]In becomes over 10 lines of code. And in the long run, it will probably cause performance problems since we're stuck doing queries with a very large amount of parameters.

Has anyone encountered and solved this problem in a more elegant and efficient way?

Comment: It _might_ be an option to write your own queries/sql and put them in stored procedures or possibly views. If you know or have an expectation, what kind of query grails should generate in your case, then give it a try. It seems, that these Queries will be a very important part of your application/system.

Answer (score 4):

This won't win any efficiency awards but I thought I'd post it as an option if you just plainly need to query a list of more than 1000 items none of the more efficient options are available/appropriate.  (This stackoverflow question is at the top of Google search results for "grails oracle 1000")

In a grails criteria you can make use of Groovy's collate() method to break up your list...

Instead of this:

```
    def result = MyDomain.createCriteria().list {
        'in'('id', idList)
    }
```

...which throws this exception:

```
could not execute query
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1616)
    at TempIntegrationSpec.oracle 1000 expression max in a list(TempIntegrationSpec.groovy:21)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
```

You'll end up with something like this:

```
    def result = MyDomain.createCriteria().list {
        or { idList.collate(1000).each { 'in'('id', it) } }
    }
```

It's unfortunate that Hibernate or Grails doesn't do this for you behind the scenes when you try to do an inList of > 1000 items and you're using an Oracle dialect.

I agree with the many discussions on this topic of refactoring your design to not end up with 1000+ item lists but regardless, the above code will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as  Juergen's comment, I've approached a similar problem by creating a DB view that flattens out user/role access rules at their most granular level (Building Site in your case?)  At a minimum, this view might contain just two columns: a Building Site ID and a user/group name.  So, in the case where a user has Direction-level access, he/she would have many rows in the security view - one row for each child Building Site of the Direction(s) that the user is permitted to access.

Then, it would be a matter of creating a read-only GORM class that maps to your security view, joining this to your other domain classes, and filtering using the view's user/role field.  With any luck, you'll be able to do this entirely in GORM (a few tips here: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-Domain-Class-and-Database-View-td3681188.html)

You might, however, need to have some fun with Hibernate: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html